# res.render doesn't load new page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a simple task.

I have a header which loads few `a` links.

```
<a class="nav-link" href="menu">Menu 1</a>
```

I am trying to load the url `/menu` from the link.

My `app.js` file

```
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/menu', index);
```

My `index.js` file

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});


/* GET new page. */
router.get('/menu', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('users', { title: 'New Page' });
});
```

The problem is it still loads the or rather refreshes the same page. I am unable to get the content from `/menu`. It still stays on the `index` page.

Just asking, any issues with the `app.engine` settings?

```
app.engine('hbs', hbs({ extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'index', layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/' }));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Comment: Can you add a console log inside `router.get('/menu')` callback to check whether it is coming into the correct route or not?

Comment: console.log works. I tried chrome incognito mode. It still doesnt work.

Comment: What is `index` in your `app.js`?

Comment: `var index = require('./routes/index');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I can not write a comment so I try to write an answer.
Make sure that the

```
./views/users.hbs
```

has a file. In the settings of the HBS, the default index is set:

```
defaultLayout: 'index'
```

And try remove

```
app.use('/menu', index);
```

is superfluous here.